# Direct3D9 / HLSL Depth semantic not working

Tags: c#, .net, directx, hlsl, pixel-shader

i have o problem with my shader code (HLSL). I use "DirectX for Managed Code" and Shader Model 3.0. I try to write a custom depth value into the depth buffer by using the DEPTH semantic in the pixel shader output struct:

```
struct PSOutput
{
    float4 col : COLOR0;
    float dept : DEPTH;
};
```

and i use this struct as return value in my pixel shader:

```
PSOutput PSFunction(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
    PSOutput output;
    ...
    output.col = float4(...);
    output.dept = ...;

    return output;
}
```

DirectX throws an exeption when i try to compile this shader, but gives no detailed information why. But when i remove the depth variable from the output struct it works! I also tried to write DEPTH0 as semantic, but no success. I hope anyone can help my with that.

EDIT:

If i write the following, it fails:

```
PSOutput PSFunction(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
    PSOutput output;

    float resDepth = input.Position[2] / input.Position[3];

    if(...)
    {
       resDepth = ...; 
    }
    output.col = float4(...);
    output.dept = resDepth;

    return output;
}
```

but if i write this code, it compiles:

```
PSOutput PSFunction(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
    PSOutput output;

    float resDepth = input.Position[2] / input.Position[3];

    if(...)
    {
       resDepth = ...; 
    }
    output.col = float4(...);
    output.dept = 0.5;

    return output;
}
```

any ideas?

Here's the full code:

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

float4 CamPos;
float4 LightDir;
float4 ObjColor;

static const float PI = 3.14159265f;

static const int MAX_FU = 32;

float fuPercent[MAX_FU];
float4 fuColor[MAX_FU];

int buildDir;
static int fuCount = 2;

float4 boxMin;
float4 boxMax;

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
    float3 ExactPos : TEXCOORD1;
};

struct PSOutput
{
    float4 col : COLOR0;
    //float dept : DEPTH;
};

VertexShaderOutput VSFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
    output.Normal = mul(input.Normal, World);
    output.ExactPos = input.Position;

    return output;
}

PSOutput PSFunction(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
    PSOutput output;

    float4 resColor = ObjColor;
    float resDepth = input.Position[2] / input.Position[3];

    float prpos = 0;

    if (buildDir == 0)
    {
        prpos = (input.ExactPos[1] - boxMin[1]) / (boxMax[1] - boxMin[1]);
    }
    else if (buildDir == 1)
    {
        prpos = 1.0 - ((input.ExactPos[1] - boxMin[1]) / (boxMax[1] - boxMin[1]));
    }
    else if (buildDir == 2)
    {
        prpos = (input.ExactPos[2] - boxMin[2]) / (boxMax[2] - boxMin[2]);
    }
    else if (buildDir == 3)
    {
        prpos = 1.0 - ((input.ExactPos[2] - boxMin[2]) / (boxMax[1] - boxMin[2]));
    }
    else if (buildDir == 4)
    {
        prpos = (input.ExactPos[0] - boxMin[0]) / (boxMax[0] - boxMin[0]);
    }
    else if (buildDir == 5)
    {
        prpos = 1.0 - ((input.ExactPos[0] - boxMin[0]) / (boxMax[0] - boxMin[0]));
    }

    float currPerc = 1.1;

    for (int i = 0; i < fuCount; i++)
    {
        if (prpos - 0.0001 <= fuPercent[i])
        {
            if (fuPercent[i] < currPerc)
            {
                currPerc = fuPercent[i];
                resColor = fuColor[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            resDepth = 1.0;
            resColor[3] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    float3 nor = input.Normal;
    float3 pos = input.ExactPos;
    float glo = 0.5;

    float id = (acos(dot(LightDir,nor) / pow(dot(LightDir,LightDir) * dot(nor, nor), 0.5))  / PI );
    id = pow(id,2);

    float3 look = reflect(normalize(pos - CamPos), nor);
    float gl = (acos(dot(LightDir,look) / pow(dot(LightDir,LightDir) * dot(look, look), 0.5))  / PI );
    gl = max(gl * 10.0 - 9.0, 0.0);
    gl = pow(gl,2) * glo;

    output.col = float4(resColor[0] * id + gl, resColor[1] * id + gl, resColor[2] * id + gl, resColor[3]);
    //output.dept = resDepth;

    return output;
}

technique MyTechnique
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VSFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PSFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If FXC is throwing an exception during compilation rather than giving you a compilation error it's probably not anything you've done wrong.

If you're using the DirectX SDK make sure you're using the most recent version (June 2010). If you're using the Windows Kit 8.0 SDK then you may have found a compiler bug. What version of the SDK / fxc are you using?

Can you post a shader that actually compiles (one with the missing VertexShaderOutput struct and without ...'s in place of actual code)? I've filled in the missing code and have no problem compiling it using fxc from Windows Kit 8.0.

EDIT:

Nope, I hadn't spotted you'd commented out the code that made it not compile.

Sure enough, it doesn't compile, but that's because it's not valid code (as reported by the compile errors). You're using the POSITION semantic as an input to your pixel shader, which is not valid. If you want to use the outputted position from a vertex shader as input to a pixel shader, copy it into a second attribute and use that instead. If I substitute the following code into your shader it then compiles:

```
struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 ClipPosition : POSITION; // Renamed this to ClipPosition.
    float4 Position : TEXCOORD0;    // This is valid to use as an input to the pixel shader.
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
    float3 ExactPos : TEXCOORD1;
};

struct PSOutput
{
    float4 col : COLOR0;
    float dept : DEPTH;
};

VertexShaderOutput VSFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.ClipPosition = mul(viewPosition, Projection); 
    output.Position = output.ClipPosition; // Copy output position to our other attribute.
    output.Normal = mul(input.Normal, World);
    output.ExactPos = input.Position;

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say, that the shader is compiled at runtime from a string. I can not post the full code, beacause this is a simplified version to show the problem. the original code has to many lines and shader parameters (i.e. some arrays). SDK is June 2010, but i will now try what happens if i use fxc. Thanks for the moment :)

Comment: Ah no, its June 2006... sorry

Comment: That's very old as SDKs go. Compiling at runtime is fine if that's what you need to do, but can you migrate to a newer SDK?

Comment: I added the full code. I removed some other techniques from the code, which are not relevant. I hope you can find a solution.

Comment: This compiles just fine for me using the latest version of fxc with the June 2010 SDK both as an 'effect' and the vertex/pixel shaders separately. You said you'd try compiling it with fxc, what happened?

If fxc throws an exception it just means that the compiler had a bug in it back in 2006 and now it doesn't and you'll either have to figure out how to rejig the code in such a way that the compiler doesn't crash or move to a newer SDK.

Comment: I hope, you realized, that in the code i posted, the affected lines are commented out. I made a test project in xna game studio 4.0, because there is more compiler information for shaders, but no success and no information. I am downloading the June 2010 SDK at the moment and i hope that this solves my problem. I need this at work and not just for fun. :(

Comment: Ah yeah, i found out the solution exactily at the same time. :) But thank you very much. Any idea why it is not possible to access the input.ClipPosition.w or input.ClipPosition[3] but the other values like input.ClipPosition.z?^^

Comment: It is my understanding that accessing any component of input.ClipPosition is not valid and will produce the following error, even if you only use x, y and z:


C:\shader.txt(30,27): error X4502: invalid input semantic 'POSITION': Legal indices are in [1,15]
C:\shader.txt(30,27): error X4502: invalid ps_3_0 input semantic 'POSITION'